# What is the source of the phrase "Satyamev Jayate"?

Tags: source

"*Satyamev Jayate*" is a very famous phrase.

What is the source the phrase "*Satyamev Jayate*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source is the [Mundaka upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145127.html)

> **satyameva jayate** nānṛtaṃ satyena panthā vitato devayānaḥ |
> yenākramantyṛṣayo hyāptakāmā yatra tat satyasya paramaṃ nidhānam || 6 ||

> 6. **Truth alone wins**, not falsehood; by truth, the Devayanah (the path of the Devas) is widened, that by which the seers travel on, having nothing to wish for to where there is that—the highest treasure attained by truth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer